# PowerShell: use "using"-like functionality in jobs to import modules including classes

Tags: powershell, object, module, parallel-processing

I have a solution in Powershell (7) where I have a module that includes a class, like

test.psm1

```
class TestClass {
    [string]$Test

    TestClass(
        [string]$_test
    ) {

        $this.Test = $_test
    }

    [void] TestMethod() {
        xxx
    }
}
```

In the main script I can successfully import the module including its classes and work with it.

In the main script I also want to process certain steps in parallel using jobs, like

```
using module .\test.psm1

[TestClass]$test = [TestClass]::new()
$job = $objects | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    [TestClass]$testJob = $using:test   
} -ThrottleLimit $ParallelJobsThrottleLimit -AsJob
```

In these jobs I want to use an object of type TestClass that has been declared outside of the parallel statement.

All my approaches so far failed with `Unable to find type`.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As of PowerShell 7.2.x, the instances of a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) passed to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) `-Parallel`, which run in parallel runspaces, do *not* see any of the *caller's* runspace state**, which includes `class` definitions.

- Hence the need for the `$using:` scope to reference values stored in the caller's *variables*.
- Unfortunately, there is *no* equivalent mechanism for custom *classes*.
- [GitHub issue #12240](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12240) discusses a *future* enhancement that will allow parallel runspaces to see at least parts of the caller's state, which would hopefully included classes.

**The problem**, in a nutshell:

- In order for parallel runspaces to see your `[TestClass]` too, they would have to import its containing module.
- However, only when you import a module via `using module` are a module's classes visible to the caller (not also when you use [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module)).
- Unfortunately, [`using` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Using) may only be placed at the *start of a script file*, and therefore cannot be used inside script *blocks*.

There are **workarounds**:

---

##### Modify your module to "export" its classes in a way that doesn't require `using module`:

- Define your `class` in a regular `.ps1` script that you reference from the `ScriptsToProcess` entry of your [module's manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Module_Manifests) file (`.psd1`)
- That way, when the module is first imported into a runspace, the `.ps1` script is dot-sourced in the *caller's* (importer's) scope, and `class` definitions therefore become visible.
- This allows you to use a regular `Import-Module` call in your parallel script block in order to see the `class` definition there.

Note that your module *itself* will *not* see such `class` definitions by default - unless you explicitly dot-source the `.ps1` file from the module's top-level code too.

---

##### Use a helper script containing a `using module` statement that you dot-source from your parallel runspaces.

You discovered this workaround yourself:

- Create a `.ps1` script that contains a `using module .\test.psm1` call, e.g., `Helper.ps1`
- From your parallel script block, dot-source this helper script (`. .\Helper.ps1`), which will make the module's classes available there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This helps. I found now a bit different but still similar approach. I created a second script with using statements that is called from the script block. It also works with $using, i.e. reusing what has been defined outside the scope of the script block. But, and that is interesting: the class in the module has a method that calls another method in the class (with $this.SomeMethod). Everything up to point of $this.SomeMethod works. Then the script just hangs. No error, nothing. It just does not proceed.

Comment: In the end I solved the problem by creating a new instance of the class in the second script. This is not optimal, but at least it works.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @quervernetzt. The hang is puzzling, and if you have a reproducible case I encourage you to create an issue at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues

Comment: @quervernetzt, I actually like your workaround better, so I've added it as an alternative to the answer. I did a quick test with one method calling another, but didn't see the problem you saw.